# __LINE__ in macro definitions, represents the line of place of macros calls

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to implement some data structures in C along with some sort of templates. 
For the counterpart of templates I use macro definitions and [this token-pasting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/token-pasting-operator-hash-hash?view=vs-2019).

For instance, let's consider this macro-function placed at queue.h:

```c
#define queue_destructor(qu)                                                   \
  {                                                                            \
    if (qu) {//53 line                                                         \
      if (qu->begin) {                                                         \
        do {                                                                   \
          void *temp = qu->begin;                                              \
          qu->begin->prev = qu->begin;                                         \
          qu->begin = qu->begin->next;                                         \
          free(temp);                                                          \
        } while (qu->begin != NULL);                                           \
      }                                                                        \
      free(qu);                                                                \
    } else {                                                                   \
      write_error_log(QUEUE_INACCESSIBILITY("queue_destructor(qu)"), __LINE__, \
                      __FILE__, "-> includes/queue.h:53");                     \
      printf(                                                                  \
          "Error has occured! Check error_log.txt for the more details.\n"     \
          "Press any key");                                                    \
      return (getchar());                                                      \
    }                                                                          \
  }
```

I'd like to write an error in file if error occurred. However the `__LINE__` represents a line of the macros' calling.

In the following example the `__LINE__` is 5.

```c
#include "queue.h"
int main(){
    //some stuff
    queue(int) *q;
    queue_destructor(q); //5th line
}
```

I comprehend, why does this happen, the macro definition substitutes into the calling place whilst compiling occurs.

So, is there a way to pass a line from macro-function?

Comment: No standard predefined macro for that. I don't know if any compilers have a non-standard macro to do it. GCC doesn't seem to have such a macro.

Comment: Do you want it to print 5 or 64?  gcc prints 5, VC++ prints 5.  Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @cup, i’d like to print 64. I’m using both compilers